# ¿Es correcto decir que un diccionario en Python tiene como elementos tuplas conformadas por la llave + valor?

Tags: python, diccionarios

La pregunta surge porque ejecute el siguiente código:

```
d = {"dni":20141907, 
 "nombres":"Karin",
 "apellidos":"Saavedra Mendoza",
 "idiomas": ["ingles" , "frances" , "español"]}
for e in d.items():
  print(e)
```

Y obtuve como salida:

```
('dni', 20141907)
('nombres', 'Karin')
('apellidos', 'Saavedra Mendoza')
('idiomas', ['ingles', 'frances', 'español'])
```

Por lo cual como la llave y el valor esta entre parentesis concluí que los elementos del diccionario son tuplas conformadas por la llave y el valor, este razonamiento es correcto?

De ser correcto el razonamiento, tengo tambien la siguiente pregunta:
Los elementos del diccionario son tuplas que son INMUTABLES pero sin embargo el diccionario NO ES INMUTABLE, como es esto posible?

Comment: No es correcto tu razonamiento, ves tuplas por qué `.items()` devuelve el contenido del diccionario en forma de tuplas. También un diccionario es mutable pero las claves deben de ser valores inmutables (y los valores pueden ser cualquiera).

Comment: puedes utilizar el metodo type() que te mostrara el tipo de elemento y ahora al pasar   dict.items por type(dict.items) veras que se hace una conversion!

Comment: Los diccionarios contienen pares de clave y valor, que items devuelva una tupla es otra cosa, no confundir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Diccionarios

Un diccionario se compone de 2 pares de datos para poder definir una estructura de dato con contenido alguno. Estos pares de datos se conocen como `key` and `value` o en español, `clave` y `valor`. Creo que esto ya lo sabes al igual de las formas de poder inicializar o crear un diccionario, por eso no entraré en detalles en esta explicación. Estos pares de datos deben de ser de un tipo específico (mutable o inmutable).

Para la `key` del diccionario se debe de indicar un valor de tipo inmutable, de lo contrario se dará un `TypeError`, y eso se puede ver con un ejemplo:

```py
d = {"key1": "value1"}
print(d)
```

Esto no dará error alguno ya que como `key` le pasamos un string que es un dato inmutable, pero si por el contrario le pasamos una lista (que es mutable) dará un `TyperError`.

```py
d = {[1]: "value1"}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-71a6ee60ee14> in <module>()
----> 1 d = {[1]: "value1"}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

### `dict.items()`

Este método retorna una los elementos del diccionario en forma de tuplas (si imprimes así `print(dict.items())` verás una *lista de tuplas* pero ese sobre-nombre es incorrecto), realmente lo que retorna es un objeto de tipo `dict_items`, y casi lo mismo para los método `dict.keys()` que retorna un `dict_keys` y `dict_values` para `dict.values()`. Pero podemos ir un poco más a fondo gracias a la documentación de python, que dice:

> `items()`
> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs). See the [documentation of view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Yendo a la [documentación de `dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) vemos que se nos especifica un poco más la cosa:

> The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items() are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes

Lo cual ya nos dice que los métodos `.keys()`, `.values()` y `.items()` son `view objects` (a mi interpretación *objetos de vista*) y este objeto representa una vista dinámica del diccionario, lo que quiere decir que si en algún momento el diccionario llega a cambiar esto se verá reflejado en el `view object`.

Lo que se nos dice sobre la vista dinámica se nos ejemplifica en la documentación, de la cual robaré el código para evitarme escribirlo.

```py
# creamos un diccionario
dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
keys = dishes.keys() # obtenemos las claves
values = dishes.values() # obtenemos los valores

#transformamos el resultado a una lista, ya que se nos devuelve un dict_keys que es un view object 

>>> list(keys) 
['eggs', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'spam']
>>> list(values)
[2, 1, 1, 500]

# borramos claves para ver el cambio dinámico del view object
del dishes['eggs']
del dishes['sausage']
# hacemos la conversión nuevamente del mismo objeto retornado por dict_keys
>>> list(keys) 
['bacon', 'spam']
```

Como puedes ver el resultado cambia y solo hemos hecho nuevamente la conversión a lista para poder ver los datos, en ningún momento hemos vuelto a llamar al método `.keys()`. Esto pasará igual para `.item()` ya que como dice la documentación estos métodos retornan un `view object`.

## Conclusiones

Sí, estabas equivocado con tu razonamiento, en realidad no se retorna una tupla, ni una lista de tuplas, se retorna un objeto de tipo `dict_items` que es en realidad, especificado en la documentación de python, un `view object` que muestra de forma dinámica el contenido del diccionario.